# entityframework There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following code that retrieves data from a customer table

```
var customers= context.CustomerEntities.Include("Addresses").Select(Mapper.Map).ToList();
```

The mapper function, maps the entity object, to a business object, and it looks like this

```
    internal static Customer Map(CustomerEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            return null;

        return new Customer
        {
            Id = entity.Id,
            Name = entity.Name,
            Addresses = Map(entity.Addresses)

        };
    }
```

Now, the above code runs well.

However, when I try to do this:

```
var customers= context.CustomerEntities.Select(Mapper.Map).ToList();
```

I get the error message: `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first` when the Mapper function is being executed.

Now I'm aware that to solve this problem, I have to set `multipleactiveresultsets=True` in my connection string. I have tried it, and it did solve my problem.

However, when I ran SQL profiler, querying all customers from entity framework automatically retrieved all the addresses as well, even though I didn't need them.

Is there a workaround besides having to set `multipleactiveresultsets=True`? I don't want the addresses to be lazy loaded all the time.

Comment: You'll probably want to check your code before your example here, I'm betting you have another context active before your code is ever fired.

Comment: No I do not have another active context

Comment: Dan, you might be onto something. let me try it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that is because for each `Customer` the select statement is causing to go and read the database again. Why don't you do first `ToList()` and then apply the mapping (`Select`)  something like:

```
var customers= context.CustomerEntities.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map);
```

I believe this would bring the data first and then do the mapping and you wouldn't have that issue.

Comment: Doing that will materialise the whole collection into memory which if you are dealing with large amounts of data is a very bad idea if you can avoid it you should.

Comment: Bit pointless downvoting unless you have something positive to contribute i.e. an alternative....